# Microsoft Excel: Moving caret with keyboard in "Edit Formatting Rule" dialog

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

When applying a conditional formatting rule in Excel, using the "Edit Formatting Rule" dialog, and using "Use a formula to determine which cells to format," you cannot move the caret (text insertion point) in the formula editor with the keyboard. If you try to use the arrow keys it inserts the cell name next to the cell in focus depending whether you hit the up/down/left/right key. Is there some way to turn this off? or some way to move the caret with the keyboard?

Comment: It was very frustrating for me too, compounded by the facts that it is the default behavior and there is no helpful reminder in the dialog box. I almost posted a duplicate of your question. Thank you, and thanks to SE for its powerful "Similar Questions" feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you enter your formula, press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enable edit mode allowing you to move the cursor with the arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks! You have no idea how much that has frustrated me.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: "After you enter your formula" I am in the middle of entering my formula and I can't press F2. What do I need to do?

Comment: @theonlygusti Did you try it? It works for that too.

Comment: @CharlieRB yes I tried it, it just plays a "boop" noise and does nothing. I'm on a mac running excel 15.27

Comment: I am unable to duplicate what you are seeing. You should probably ask your own question.

Comment: @CharlieRB—I'm running Excel Mac 2011 and Excel behaves as theonlygusti says. I find this "feature" insanely annoying.